# Rearranging DOM elements based on text content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let's say I have a structure which looks like this:

```html
<dl class="item-options">
  <dt>Option name 1</dt>
  <dd>Option 1 value</dt>
  <dt>Option name 2</dt>
  <dd>Option 2 value</dt>
  <dt>Option name 3</dt>
  <dd>Option 3 value</dt>
  <dt>Super option</dt>
  <dd>Super option value</dt>
  <dt>Super option 2</dt>
  <dd>Super option 2 value</dt>
  <dt>Option name 4</dt>
  <dd>Option 4 value</dt>
</dl>
```

What I need is move 'Super option' 1 and 2 and values (ie. both the `dd` and `dt`) to the top of the list. Like this:

```html
<dl class="item-options">
  <dt>Super option</dt>
  <dd>Super option value</dt>
  <dt>Super option 2</dt>
  <dd>Super option 2 value</dt>
  <dt>Option name 1</dt>
  <dd>Option 1 value</dt>
  <dt>Option name 2</dt>
  <dd>Option 2 value</dt>
  <dt>Option name 3</dt>
  <dd>Option 3 value</dt>
  <dt>Option name 4</dt>
  <dd>Option 4 value</dt>
</dl>
```

jQuery was ok in this case so I tried this:

```
var optionName = $('.item-options dt')
var check = optionName.text();
if (check.indexOf("Super option") >= 0) {
  elem.next().text();
}
```

This returns the whole list of option values. It looks like I did not get right the concept of the solution in general. Is this correct that I need to grab the next element if `indexOf` check returned 'yes'?

**P.S: I forgot to mention (my bad sorry) that option value is always a different thing. It could be some text, or number. So this value is not static.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way to do this would be to select the `dt` and `dd` elements using `:contains("Super")` then `prepend()` them to the `dl`, as below. The order will be retained as they are prepended in the order they were selected.

```js
$('dt:contains("Super"), dd:contains("Super")').prependTo('.item-options');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dl class="item-options">
  <dt>Option name 1</dt>
  <dd>Option 1 value</dd>
  <dt>Option name 2</dt>
  <dd>Option 2 value</dd>
  <dt>Option name 3</dt>
  <dd>Option 3 value</dd>
  <dt>Super option</dt>
  <dd>Super option value</dd>
  <dt>Super option 2</dt>
  <dd>Super option 2 value</dd>
  <dt>Option name 4</dt>
  <dd>Option 4 value</dd>
</dl>
```

Also note that you have used `</dt>` instead of `</dd>` in some places

Comment: Thanks good Sir. But I forgot to mention (my bad sorry) that option value is always a different thing. It could be some text, or number. So this value is not static

Comment: The approach is still the same, just change the value used in `:contains` (or even `filter()` depending on how complex the string match needs to be)

Comment: @AL_ST So put the needed string in a variable and use that instead of a static value.

Answer (score 0):

A vanilla solution to re-insert the elements atop of the childnode list:

What does it do:

1. It gets all `dt` nodes using `querySelectorAll`.
2. Convert de nodeList to Array with `Array.from`
3. Filter all elements out of it that have `Super option #` in it.
4. reverse the array since we use `insertBefore` to insert elements before the zero-indexed child.
5. Loop over all `array` elements and perform a `while loop` on all direct siblings (using `nextElementSibling` to prevent `textnodes`) that are of node name `DD` and re-insert them.
6. Re-insert the elements at position `0`.

```js
const nodes = document.querySelectorAll("dt");
const dl = document.querySelector("dl.item-options");

//convert nodelist to array
Array.from(nodes).filter( element => element.textContent.match(/Super option ?\d{0,}/)).reverse().forEach(element => {
  //use the index to make sure the elements end up in the correct order.
  let index = 0;
  do{
    dl.insertBefore(element.nextElementSibling, dl.children[index]);
    index++;
  }
  while(element.nextElementSibling && element.nextElementSibling.nodeName == "DD");
  dl.insertBefore(element, dl.children[0]);
});
```

```html
<dl class="item-options">
   <dt>Option name 1</dt>
   <dd>Option 1 value</dd>
   <dt>Option name 2</dt>
   <dd>Option 2 value</dd>
   <dt>Option name 3</dt>
   <dd>Option 3 value</dd>
   <dt>Super option</dt>
   <dd>Super option value</dd>
   <dt>Super option 2</dt>
   <dd>Value S2_1</dd>
   <dd>Value S2_2</dd>
   <dd>Value S2_3</dd>
   <dd>Value S2_4</dd>
   <dt>Option name 4</dt>
   <dd>Option 4 value</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: Im really appreciate your help. I forgot to mentioned that <dd> with values are always different..

Comment: That makes things a little more difficult, however adding a while loop to the logic to loop over all sibling `DD` does the trick.